Почему не получается спарсить названия учебных заведений?
Есть сайт: https://net-school.cap.ru/authorize/login
На главной странице есть , который отвечает за выбор названия учебного заведения
Я пытаюсь спарсить эти названия, но не получается
Остановился на том, что request просто не видит этот тэг
Вот код:
# импортируем модуль
import requests
st_accept = "text/html" # говорим веб-серверу,
                        # что хотим получить html
# имитируем подключение через браузер Mozilla на macOS
st_useragent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 12_3_1) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.4 Safari/605.1.15"
# формируем хеш заголовков
headers = {
   "Accept": st_accept,
   "User-Agent": st_useragent
}
# отправляем запрос с заголовками по нужному адресу
req = requests.get("https://net-school.cap.ru/authorize/login", headers)
# считываем текст HTML-документа
src = req.text
print(src)


Открой для себя авторизацию.

Вероятно, вы не авторизовались, в таком случае нужно узнать куки авторизации и отправить их с запросом:
resp = get('https://example.com', headers = headers, cookies = cookies)
print(resp.text)

